# Who gets notification when commented on a CW?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies

In a community wiki, lots of people contribute by editing the post. So when a comment is done on the post, who gets the notification? All the contributors till date or the latest contributor? Or none?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)

> - The **first author** of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment.
> - You can explicitly notify one (1) other commenter, **editor**, or ♦ moderator who closed a question.
> - Use @name, where name is the username with all spaces removed.

(emphasis mine)

So without any @-names in the comment, only the first author - that is, the person who created the post - will be notified. Other authors (editors) can be notified by adding @*name* to the comment (where *name* is the username of the editor with spaces removed).

These rules are the same for CW and normal posts, though it can be more worth your while to look up the editor responsible for the portion being commented on in the revision history for CW posts.

Answer (score 3):

Lets find out, edit me at will, comment away. Editing to see what happens!!! Re-edited, just to make sure

Comment: So what happens now? Got anything in notification?

Comment: I got nothing(it should be!). Did you?

Comment: I (unsuprisingly) got a notification as the OP on comments and edits

Comment: @Mistu4u only the post author get notification when comment is posted (Richard in this case) and pretty recent change also send notification when a non trivial edit is made.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, Hope you get this notification.

Comment: Assuming @Mistu4u didn't get notifications on either my edit, or my last comment then we can confirm the behaviour and put this one to bed. Interestingly badges still come from CW, I got a necromancer badge off one

Comment: Some badges do, some badges don't. In particular, tag badges ignore CW.

Comment: @Shog9 Interesting, I felt bad because I had specifically CWed it because I had actually just taken the OP's own answer out of the question and put it as an answer

Comment: @Mistu4u yes, got it - as far as it's related to notifications Community Wiki post is not different than ordinary post. :)